# Zip all parent folders and subdirectories separate. Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, automation

So I have a bash I use to zip each folder as its named.zip. However it zips sub folders into the same as its parent.

```
Example
  Example 1
  Example 2
  Example 3
Example-me
  Example 12
  Example 21
Example-nosubdir
```

All end up in Example.zip or as Example-me. How can I make it zip directories with no sub directory as well as recognizing a sub directory and only zipping the sub directories?

Here is what I have been using.

```
for i in */; do zip -r "${i%/}.zip" "$i"; done
```

Trying to make that work to do what is specified above.
Thanks

Comment: What you've been testing and therefore any answers have nothing to do with Windows NT command scripts, I have therefore removed the batch-file tag from your question. If you wish to re-add it, do so only after you've adjusted your question/code to suit.

Comment: Fixed to correct any confusion.